# How can I display my photos from mysql database of single row

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I made a form where I upload multiple photos and then stored them on a single row in my database. How can I echo all the photos? Below is my sample code trying to display the photos from database and screenshot of my database and how it look like when I run the code.

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/admin/add/commsheetConnect.php'); ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .comms-image img{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<?php   
    $conn = mysqli_connect(db_host, db_username, db_password, db_name, db_port);
    $sql = "SELECT image FROM comms_images";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo "<div class='comms_image'>";
        //DISPLAY IMAGE
        echo "<img src='/project/decors/photos/comms_img/".$row['image']."'>";
    }
?>
```

What the photos look like in my database:
[image]

What the code looks like when I run it:

[image: second image]

Comment: Do not store the data like that. Store one photo per row.

Comment: You could use `explode` or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php but you really should fix the schema issue now before it becomes a large issue. (e.g. a file has a comma in its name, you need to find one row in your table that has a particular name, etc)

Comment: You should save one image per row just like @user3783243 said.

Comment: Don't bother with this design. Remove that column from the database and instead create a dedicated table for images. Never store comma-separated values in the database.

Comment: I recommend do not store the image inside the table. I upload the file into the server with copy(). I just save in the table the original name and the name I use to save the image.

Comment: Oh so storing files separated with comma is bad? I'm sorry I'm a newbie in MySQL.

Comment: thank you all so much! ill fix now my database